# Selecting a cell based on values in other cells

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to simply select a cell based on the data in cell A1 and cell B1.

For example A1=3 and B1=6.

What is the code to get VBA to select the cell (row 3,column 6)

Values in A1 and B1 will change. I am trying to select the cell based on the value in those cells.

Thanks very much.

Comment: in the end to do what?

Comment: To add to Scott, you just want to select the cell???

Comment: the reason we ask, depending on what you want to do there may be better methods than others.

Comment: `Cells(row, Column).Select` will do what you want assuming the appropriate sheet is already selected.  Try that out and post back with code if you run into problems

Comment: I believe the laziest possible answer is `Cells(Range("A1"),Range("B1")).Select`. Somebody prove me wrong.

Comment: Laziest possible is probably `Cells([A1],[B1]).Select`

Comment: Touche. I never think of `[]`

Comment: I don't ever use it, but it's there...

Comment: Another example if you want the value of the cell with that address, you could just use a formula `=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(A1,B1))`

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub selectCell()
xRow = Range("A1").Value
xCol = Range("B1").Value

Cells(xRow, xCol).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you not read the comments?  @TimWilliams and EntryLevel already covered this.